# MTN bike tyre sidewall wear question

Tags: tire

I’ve noticed some wear in my mtn bike tyre sidewalls.  Is this serious or can I get many more km from them?

[image: tyre sidewall 1]

[image: tyre picture 2]

Comment: Go tell they die.  It is a lightweight tire with a thin sidewall.

Comment: Is there anything rubbing on the sidewall? Do you tend to ride on very low air pressure?

Comment: Find out what they are rubbing on and why. Fix that issue, then replace the tyres. If tyres are worn to the canvas / casing they should be replaced.

Comment: @KeithWM That is not rubbing.  That is thin wall flaking off.   If it holds air then you can ride it.

Comment: It's unclear whether the pattern in the picture is due to rubbing against the frame (or an awful lot of running along the edge of a curb or whatever) or instead some sort of breakdown of the sidewall (possibly due to underinflation).  As to how serious the problem is, I'd say it represents 50-70% of the life of the tire has been spent.  (Depends somewhat on how much you value reliability.)  The tire's unlikely to fail catastrophically until it gets about twice that bad, but it could begin to bulge sooner, so one needs to keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Paparazzi thanks - not seen that happen to a tyre just from riding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the knobs, that looks like a Continental X-King, but not the 'Protection' version as no checker pattern on the sidewall.

What you show in the pictures is quite normal to see on X-Kings (and some other tyres), and its quite safe to ride.  All that has happened is some of the very thin outer coating has worn off, but the structure of the tyre will be intact.

See [review from Pro rider](http://scottrcmtb.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/conti-x-king-race-king-29x22-protection.html) for an even more extreme example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  You are correct it is a continental X-King RaceSport (so not protection).  The back tyre looks the same on the sidewall but needs replacing as the tread has worn down.  As the sidewall is not an issue I might get another RaceSport as the sidewall is lasting longer than the tread anyway - at least on the back.  Only I might get it in mountain King II form rather than X-King for better grip.